# How to reset variables to their original value? Python

Tags: python

```
number01 = 12
number02 = 20
number01 + 1
number02 + 2
print(number01) #prints :13
print(number02) #prints : 22

(reset all variables)

print(number01) #prints :12  
print(number02) #prints :12`
```

I have looked at other posts but they did not answer my question! How do I reset all variables to their default value? So that you can run your game multiple times.

Comment: Can you edit your post to put the program in a code block with proper new lines. What you've written is hard to understand.

Comment: Not sure if you made a typo but doing `number01 + 1` will not add one to the value stored in `number01`. Perhaps you meant `number01 += 1`

Answer (score 2):

There is no default value in python. I do not know if any language at all has that construct. If you need to store the value of a variable while doing other operations with them, you need to use another temporary variable

```
number01 = 12
number02 = 20
print(number01) # 12
print(number02) # 20

old_number01 = number01
old_number02 = number02
number01 += 1
number02 += 2
print(number01) # 13
print(number02) # 22

number01 = old_number01
number02 = old_number02
print(number01) # 12
print(number02) # 20
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the numbers are reset to their original value if `number01` is 12 again. Printing `number01 + 1` should not change the variable. Constructs like the following would change the value:

```
number01 += 1
```

or

```
number01 = number01 + 1
```

Once changed, `number01 = 12` would set it back.

If this does not address your question, please show the exact code, using 4 spaces before each code line.

Answer (score 1):

For this I'd consider having the originals saved in a global variable and a function that sets the variables to this original value.

```
number01 = 12
number02 = 20

num1Or = number01  
num2Or = number02

def resetVar():
    global number01, number02
    number01 = num1Or
    number02 = num2Or

number01 += 1  
number02 += 2  

print(number01) 
print(number02) 

resetVar() 

print(number01)
print(number02)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the original values to some global variables, and then don't change those variables.

```
original_number_01 = 12
original_number_02 = 02

// Do some stuff without changing either of the above...

print(original_number_01)
print(original_number_02)
```

A program is just a sequence of instructions, and, from a bird's-eye view, it stores data if and only if you tell it to. And the only way to do so is through variable assignment, either explicit (writing a variable assignment yourself) or implicit (calling a function with side-effects).